# React useRef hook by creating a dynamic select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

During the construction of a select, I need to verify that no duplicate "option" elements are created.

I thought that one way to do this is to use the useRef hook. But I am confused by the behavior. I am sure that I am doing something wrong or I am not considering some aspects.

I wrote a small sample code, which I show below:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const options = ["de-de", "en-gb", "es-es", "fr-fr", "it-it", "nl-be"];
  let selectRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Control as="select" custom ref={selectRef}>
            {options.map((cc) => {
              console.log("selectRef", selectRef, "cc", cc);
              return (
                <option key={cc} value={cc}>
                  {cc}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I add a link to https://stackblitz.com where the code of the shown example is present: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jlwttg?file=src/App.js

The behavior is bizarre: with every iteration where I add a new option on the console, I see that my reference's current value already has all the elements. How is it possible? Where am I doing wrong? Also, I noticed that if I refresh my page my reference is always null.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi,
I apologize; I missed clarifying that I omitted the reason for the possibility of duplication in my real context. The example code it's created evidence the apparent anomalies in the useRef usage. 
Thank you very much again.